# Function with Short data type is running way to different than with double

Tags: java, double, type-conversion, short

I have two functions which I thought to be quit simular despite from they are using different data types:

```
public double[] getdoubleArray(){
      final String[] myStringArray = oldArray[0].split(",");
      double[] d = new double[myStringArray.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < d.length -1; i++){
          d[i] = Double.parseDouble(myStringArray[i]);
}
    return d;
  }
```

this works as it should.

```
public short[] getshortArray(){
      final String[] myStringArray = oldArray[1].split(",");
      short[] s = new short[myStringArray.length];
      for(int i = 0; i < s.length -1; i++){
          s[i] = Short.parseShort(myStringArray[i]);
}
    return s;
  }
```

this function is called shortly after the one above and every time it is in the loop with i = 1 it is being interrupted by an other Thread or the ZygoteInit class. but when I change the data type to double then it works fine.(Exept for the fact that I neet a short array)
Can anyone explain this or has a sulution?

EDIT
1. I don´t get an exeption. When i debug I usually end up some where between the lines where isn´t actual code.

2. The data in the string can´t be the problem since I copied it form a short array that worked. (the string in oldArray[1] is this: "0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 4")

Comment: Did you notice that one method uses `oldArray[0]` and the other `oldArray[1]`?

Comment: @Eran sorry typo... corrected it... the oldArray  index is ment to be different.

Comment: What about my first comment?

Comment: You are trying to convert String to short, which would give number format exception.

Comment: What do you mean by interrupted by another thread? Are you getting an Exception? If so can you put that stack trace?

Comment: @Eran the index must me different. It is an other data set

Comment: Perhaps `oldArray[1]` contains problematic data, which causes the failure (i.e. Strings that can't be parsed as short). You should include more information in your question.

Comment: can you give examples of the strings you are trying to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is spaces in your input string. `Double.parseDouble` tolerates spaces, while `Short.parseShort` throws `NumberFormatException` when they are encountered. Try `Short.parseShort(myStringArray[i].trim())`.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Is working perfectly now thank you!!